# How can we position the auto scroll of a winform at the top?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can we position the auto scroll of a winform at the top? Currently it is automatically scrolling to bottom of the form.

Comment: We'll need to see some code as well as what kind of form you are talking about: Web Forms, WinForms, WPF Pages, ... ?

Comment: @vincent. I am talking about winform

Comment: What are you using to facilitate the scrolling ? Are you using some kind of container? Or are we talking about a DataGrid / ListBox / ... on a Form instead? You're gonna have to provide a lot more info than what you've given so far. Especially if you've got some freak behavior...

Answer (score 5):

```
this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0,0);
```

Where 'this' is the form.

Answer (score 4):

Set Focus to a control at the top.
Winforms scrolls to the control that has focus

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - please could you expand on your answer and respond to the original question with as much information about your solution as possible.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to scroll to a certain control and in the Form that contains mycontrol I did:

```
mycontrol.Focus();
```

wich scrolls to the Control

Answer (score 0):

If your form has a panel controls click "View" -> "Tab Order" and click the panel first. The tab's Tab Order will change to 0. This will automatically focus the first panel in the form.